# Nextjs13 not revalidating data

Tags: next.js, sanity

I made a blog with Nextjs 13 a while ago with Sanity CMS. I made a post and left it for a while in the development server it seemed fine probably because it runs the server side code everytime. Now if I try to add a new blog it does not appear (i have a revalidate of 10). But when i edit an old blog like the title it does change the title inside the blog but not in the home page where all blogs are present. I am using the same function for fetching the blogs on both of them so idk why this happens.
**Github repo -** https://github.com/APS6/my-blog
here is the function

```
import { client } from "@/sanity/lib/client";

export default async function getBlogs() {
    const query = '*[_type == "post"]';
    const data = await client.fetch(query, {
      next: {revalidate: 10 }
    });
  
    if (!data) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }
  
    return data;
  }
```

and the page

```
import getBlogs from "./utils/getBlogs";

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getBlogs();
```

I tried adding a revalidate, no store but both seemed to have no effect. site is hosted in vercel.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this or make progress with it? I'm running Next 13.4 and I thought the revalidation was fine, but recently it seems to have stopped revalidating very well at all.

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Adding export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'fixes it as mentioned in the nextjs article for caching https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34840792)